# How can I get a twitter bootstrap datepicker to work with Meteor?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I would rather use the Meteor package implementation of Bootstrap rather than the less files version but I am having a hell of a time getting a datepicker to work.

There seem to be three versions in varying states with the last one by Aymkdn being compiled and ready to go.

http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/

https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/

https://github.com/Aymkdn/Datepicker-for-Bootstrap

The version by Aymkdn works fine in plain vanilla html but not served from Meteor and I am having a helluva time figuring out why.

I would like to use the one by Aymkdn with Meteor but I cannot get it to work.  I think it may have to do with either the js loading order in Meteor or the DOM rendering.  Any insights into how I can get this to work?

Thanks
Steeve

Comment: bootstrap-datepicker is now a smart package on Meteor. Just `meteor add bootstrap-datepicker`

Comment: It isn't listed here http://docs.meteor.com/#packages. Do you mean it is an mrt package maybe?

Comment: Try `meteor list`. Do you find it there?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Perhaps this approach wasn't available when this question was originally posted, but I'm initializing the datepicker when its template is rendered.

```
Template.templateName.rendered = function() {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker();
}
```

Here is a link to the event: http://docs.meteor.com/#template_rendered

With this approach, I don't have maintain a session property or handle focus events. Prashant's solution didn't work for me when the template was unloaded and returned to since the session property was tripped. I also had an issue wherein the datapicker didn't display the first time it got focus.

Yes, the datapicker will get initialized each time the template is rendered, but I think that's okay since I'm pretty sure template resources are cleaned up when navigating between them anyway.

Answer (score 2):

To get the datepicker to work, this is what I did,

```
// At the beginning of the script
Session.set("datepicker_unset", 1);

Template.template_name.events = {
    'focus #date-id' : function(event) {
        if (Session.get("datepicker_unset")) {
            $(event.target).datepicker();
            Session.set("datepicker_unset", 0);
        }
        // Anything else on #date-id focus?
    },
    // Any other events here
}
```

I am guessing that you are using, `$(document).ready()` approach. I did too, and since it did not work for me, I figured this would be the best solution.

Hope this works for you too!

Comment: Do I have to do it as a package?  Or can it go in /client?

Comment: Yes you can add it to /client and it will start working. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: You should probably only ever need to call .datepicker() once. This will call it every time the focus event is fired. This will set up the datepicker each time.

Comment: Thank you for noticing that. Edited so that datepicker() is not fired everytime. I've used Session class for that.

Comment: This is working fine but I am unable to pick datetimepicker from bootstrap. datepicker are working but not the datetimepicker. Thanx