# Does one need to explicitly set the content-type from Meteor for Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, meteor

I was trying to make use of the twitter bootstrap datepicker as described here: [How can I get a twitter bootstrap datepicker to work with Meteor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11932485/how-can-i-get-a-twitter-bootstrap-datepicker-to-work-with-meteor/12041281#12041281)

I'm including the client side libraries in the Meteor client directory, rather than creating a package.

I've noticed that under Chrome Canary I get the following on the included `datepicker.js`: 'Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html', however, Safari recognizes it as an application/javascript file.  Although Safari doesn't seem to properly recognize it either, as I get a SyntaxError:

> Unexpected Token '<' console message on bootstrap-datepicker.js.

Is there a way to explicitly set the content-type on the Meteor server side?  Or, am I doing something else wrong?

*** EDIT ***
I'm an idiot.  I was including the bootstrap-datepicker.js in my application's HTML file.  Didn't realize Meteor took care of that for you.

Comment: Hi. Sorry for digressing a bit. But I used pikaday plugin for datepicker http://dbushell.com/2012/10/09/pikaday-javascript-datepicker/ - which I had no trouble with - that is, of course if you don't have to use twitter bootstrap.

Comment: @dbexternal you can delete your question if it's no longer applicable! :)

Answer (score 0):

Answer copied from edited question body so it can be accepted:

> I was including the bootstrap-datepicker.js in my application's HTML file. Didn't realize Meteor took care of that for you.